# Execute a python script from within another, pass argument and return global variable

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, arguments, execute

I am attempting to create a job scheduler in Python. The scheduler (i.e. the parent script) will then run child scripts (also in Python).

It seems the best way to do this would be via subprocess, which appeals as I want to be able to cancel/timeout the process/script in question if it takes too long to run.

The script I am trying to run takes an argument. Critically, it also returns an object (which I then want to then refer to in the parent script, once the child job has completed).

I'm able to successfully pass the argument to the child script and execute it. However, I'm not sure how to receive the object the child script "returns". So, if for example my child script was designed to return a dictionary, I'd like to then refer to the data in that dictionary in my parent script.

Obviously if this needs to be done via a different means then that's fine, but it's critical I can kill the process and pass arguments to any child scripts.

Example code:

```
import subprocess
my_timeout_in_seconds = 60
job_data = subprocess.run([sys.executable, path_to_my_script, argument_to_pass],
                          shell=False, timeout=my_timeout_in_seconds)
```

Comment: This should be relatively straight forward if you understand how subprocess works, I would look into subprocess messages and have your other script return the dictionary as a message. check out [this question about messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098327/program-called-with-subprocess-logger-messages-are-not-printed)

Comment: Thank you C. Lewis - that makes sense. I'll take a look at in more detail. Thanks for the suggestion